# Cant create a VG . /dev/sda1: already exists in filesystem

Tags: linux, lvm, raid

Tried creating an LVM VG but getting this error

```
sudo vgcreate /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 vg0
/dev/sda1: already exists in filesystem
```

I've already removed all the VG, LV, and PV. I tried removing all the partitions and `wipefs`, but it still does not work

Comment: What happens if you order it like:
sudo vgcreate vg0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1

Comment: My bad , I was just using Wrong command. Noob move from my part.
The command should be sudo vgcreate  vg0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the arguments in the wrong order. Quoting from the documentation (`man vgcreate`)

> **EXAMPLES**
> Create a VG with two PVs, using the default physical extent size.
>
> ```
> vgcreate myvg /dev/sdk1 /dev/sdl1
> ```

The `vgcreate` command is complaining because you're telling it to create a VG called `/dev/sda1`. Try this instead

```
vgcreate vg0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```